# Is there any interface to create this special diagonal matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix

suppose we have matrix m, is there any quick way to create matrix like:

```
  m
    m
      m
        m
```

without using loop?

I have tried using matrix concatenating, it works but too complicated.
Hope there is more concise way to do that.

Comment: What, ***exactly***, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to build a special diagonal matrix in which matrix `m` appears in the diagonal repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much information about what what libraries you may be using, but assuming that `m` is a number and you are using `numpy` for your matrix representation, you should be able to do:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> n = 3
>>> m = 5
>>> numpy.identity(n) * m
array([[ 5.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  5.]])
```

where `n` is the dimension of your matrix, and `m` is the number you want to fill the diagonal.